# How to tell chrome to run a script when a website is loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've written a script and I want it to be opened every time a special website is opened in my chrome browser. What should I do?

P.S: You can be find the answer in the first comment thanks to  @epascarello.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en

Comment: You can create an Extension for chrome.which handles all the webpages. like  vpn extensions encrypts all the websites ,similarly your extension runs the script for all pages.

Comment: @epascarello : Thanks guys. How can I mark my question as solved?